# Seguridad al guardar y servir archivos pdf con PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, tcpdf

Realizando un sistema para generar y servir posteriormente ficheros pdf, estando por detrás de una zona de acceso restringido, me gustaría saber sí es un sistema seguro y minimizar los problemas de seguridad. Adjunto los archivos realizados.

El formulario para introducir el texto y referencia del pdf.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title>Generar pdf</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <h1> Generar pdf </h1>
                <form method='post' action="generar_pdf.php">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="referencia" class="form-label">Referencia</label>
                        <input type="text" name='referencia' class="form-control" id="referencia" aria-describedby="textHelp"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="text_pdf" class="form-label">Text</label>
                        <textarea name='text_pdf' class="form-control" id="text_pdf" aria-describedby="textHelp"></textarea>
                        <div id="textHelp" class="form-text">Generació pdf amb el text.</div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Generar</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

El fichero .php para generar y guardar el pdf en el servidor

```html
<?php

require_once("/var/www/html/tcpdf/tcpdf.php");
require_once("/var/www/html/tcpdf/include/tcpdf_fonts.php");

$ref = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "referencia", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$text = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "text_pdf", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

class MYPDF extends TCPDF {

    protected $regularFont = "Helvetica";

    //Construct
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
        $this->SetFont($this->regularFont, '', 9);
    }
    //Page header
    public function Header() 
    {
        
    }

    // Page footer
    public function Footer() 
    {
        
    }
}


$pdf = new MYPDF();

$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('VL');
$pdf->SetTitle('VL');
$pdf->SetSubject('VL');
$pdf->SetKeywords('VL');

// set default header data
$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING);

// set header and footer fonts
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

// set default monospaced font
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

// set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

// set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

// set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

$pdf->AddPage();

$x = 10;
$y = 10;
$pdf->MultiCell(190, 14, $text, 0, 'L', false, 1, $x, $y, true);


$str = str_shuffle("AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlNnMmOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwYyZz0123456789");
$ct = time();

$file = "F" . $ref . "_" . $ct . "_" . $str .".pdf"; 
$pdf->Output('/var/www/html/web/assets/pdf/test/'.$file, 'FI');

//Guardamos los datos
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=ddbb;charset=utf8','user', 'password');
$sql_insert_file = "INSERT INTO ddbb.file_pdf (referencia, fichero) VALUES (?,?)";
$smt_insert_file = $pdo->prepare($sql_insert_file);
$smt_insert_file->execute(array($ref,$file));
//Fin guardar los datos

return;
```

Posteriormente, genero una tabla para obtener los pdfs, y poder servirlo.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.0.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css">
        <title>Documentos pdf</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <h1>Documentos pdf</h1>
                    <table id="tabla_pdfs" class="table table-striped" style="width:100%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Id</th>
                                <th>Referencia</th>
                                <th>Descarga</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/test_pdf.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

```html
$(function() {
    var table = $('#tabla_pdfs').DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": "test_pdfs.php"
        },
        "columns": [
            {"data": "id"},
            {"data": "referencia"},
            {"data": null}
        ],
        "iDisplayLength":10,
        "fnCreatedRow": function(nRow,aData,iDataIndex) {
            var fichero = aData.fichero;
            var link = "<a target='_blank' href='pdf_server.php?fichero="+fichero+"'>PDF</a>";
            $('td:eq(2)',nRow).html(link);
        },
    });
});
```

Php para devolver las filas con los archivos guardados y construir la tabla.

```html
<?php

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=ddbb;charset=utf8','user', 'password');

$sql_files = "SELECT id, referencia, fichero FROM ddbb.file_pdf ";
$smt_files = $pdo->prepare($sql_files);
$smt_files->execute();
echo json_encode(array("data"=>$smt_files->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)));
return;
```

Y finalmente el php para devolver el fichero pdf:

```html
<?php

$fichero = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "fichero", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$path = '/var/www/html/web/assets/pdf/test/'.$fichero;

$amb_file = basename($path);

$attachment_location = $path;
if (file_exists($attachment_location)) 
{
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); // return mime type ala mimetype extension
    $mime = finfo_file($finfo, $attachment_location);

    //header('Cache-Control: public'); // needed for i.e.
    header("Content-Type: {$mime}");
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($attachment_location));
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$amb_file);
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    ob_end_clean();
    readfile($attachment_location);
    exit(); 
} 
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
return;
```

Para finalizar decir que he indicado al .htaccess la opción Options -Indexes para no poder listar los ficheros en los directorios del proyecto.

Comment: El archivo se guarda en `/var/www/html/web/assets/pdf/test/` no? esa ubicación pareciera ser accesible y no sería necesario.

Comment: Si, se guarda en esa ruta. ¿Qué quieres decir con que no es necesario que lo fuera? Para escribir y generar el pdf debe serlo no?

Comment: accesible desde afuera, con un navegador por ejemplo, si alguien conociera la ruta lo podria descargar. php puede acceder a carpetas no accesibles, podrias guardarlo en `/var/www/pdf` por ejemplo.

Comment: Es cierto, pero la carpeta no es accesible desde navegador al añadir en el .htaccess Options -Indexes

Comment: el indexes previene que liste las carpetas y archivos,  pero si pones la ruta exacta entiendo que la va a devolver.

Comment: Ok, entonces la carpeta donde se guardan los pdfs mejor fuera de /html/

Comment: yo creo que si. Dicho sea de paso, ahora google no le da importancia al robots.txt osea que indexa todo, si no le ponemos el  -Indexes incluso aparece el contenido en los resultados de búsquedas.